# Get Azure VM creation date

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-explorer

Is there a possible way to get the VM creation date ?

I've tried the following by now

```
AzureActivity
| where TimeGenerated > ago(90d)
| where ResourceProvider == "Microsoft.Compute" and OperationName == "Create or Update Virtual Machine"
| project Resource ,Datum = format_datetime(EventSubmissionTimestamp, 'MM') ,Caller
| distinct Datum , Resource , Caller
| order by Datum
```

This kusto query will read the logs from the VM's connected to it. and get all the Create or update virtual machine operations from a vm and its caller ID.

But this is create and **update** So it gives me double values every time an VM is being updated.

I tried also in PowerShell

```
$GetVM = Get-AzureRMVM
Foreach ($vms in $GetVM)
{
$vm = get-azurermvm -name $vms.Name -ResourceGroupName $vms.ResourceGroupName
$log = Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceId $vm.Id -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-90) -WarningAction silentlyContinue 
Write-Output "- Found VM creation at $($log.EventTimestamp) for VM $($log.Id.split("/")[8]) in Resource Group $($log.ResourceGroupName) found in Azure logs"  
}
```

But Can't seem to find the creation date inside the log files either. Does anyone have a clue if it is possible to find the creation date of a Virtual Machine inside a scripting language , Kusto , Powershell , ...

Comment: Have you tried this? https://savilltech.com/2018/02/13/checking-the-creation-time-of-an-azure-iaas-vm/ There seems to be no built-in way otherwise

Comment: I have looked deeper in the solution you provided and this actually did the trick for me. If you change your comment in an answer i will accept this.

Comment: done :) see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to find out the creation date if it's later than 90 days. But here is a nice workaround solution: https://savilltech.com/2018/02/13/checking-the-creation-time-of-an-azure-iaas-vm/

Comment: broken link....

Comment: This is why it's a requirement to submit excerpts in your answer and not just a hyperlink. -1

I found the answer on [WayBackMachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20221007132740/https://savilltech.com/2018/02/13/checking-the-creation-time-of-an-azure-iaas-vm/)

edit: I can't edit the answer to place in the relevant code due to SO limits. Will try again later

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way that worked for me to get the Azure VM creation date was to ***look at the creation date of the OS Disk***

1. Browse to your VM on Azure Portal
2. On Left Hand side, click on the blade "Disks"
3. Under OS Disk section, click on your OS Disk.
4. In the Overview blade of your OS Disk, you can see ***Time Created field***.

Note: All my Azure VMs were created with the OS Disk and were never changed.

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use azure cli

use below command

```
az vm list
```

This will list json data with fields and you can filter

```
date = vm['timeCreated']
```

//"timeCreated": "2022-06-24T14:13:00.326985+00:00",

Answer (score 1):

The portal does show Created for a cloud service in the Dashboard of a Cloud Service, but that is not shown for a specific VM (which you can see with Azure PowerShell with `Get-AzureService <cloud service name> | select DateCreated`).

When you do a Quick Create of a VM, that will always create a new cloud service, so the time created would be the same for VM and cloud service. But since you can add multiple VMs to a cloud service, you can't always rely on that.

On the VM's Dashboard in the portal, at the bottom if you look at the VHD column, the VHD name includes the date the disk was created as part of the name, though this is only true for VMs created from an image. If the VM was created from a disk, the name could be anything. You can get that OS disk name in Azure PowerShell with `Get-AzureVM <cloud service name> <VM name> | Get-AzureOSDisk | select medialink`.

Operation Logs under Management Services in the portal lets you search the last 30 days for operations, so if the VM was created in the last month, you can find evidence of the operation there (for example `CreateHostedService` and `CreateDeployment` operations).

For Windows VMs created from an image, the timestamp on `WaSetup.log` and `WaSetup.xml` in `C:\Windows\panther\` reflect when the VM was provisioned.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The command you provided did not work for me. But the idea however did trigger something. Ive created a small script that do the same concept. However if a VM has an unmanaged disk this concept does not work. Which will create grey spots if I want to get the VM's that have been created in the last 90 days

Comment: Yes as such there is no full proof solution available , these are just alternative for the same. that's why i have talked about multiple options.

Comment: Your solutions are very usefull but the solution of @silent did the trick because it gave me the creation date of all vm's no matter which disk I used. And so I can't but give him the accept answer. But your answer was equally valueble; Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you check Deployments in the respective resource group, you will see Last Modified date for each of the deployment in that RG.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to get it working for me by tweaking your ActivityLog query instead of Powershell. Using the HTTPRequest property seemed to give me what I needed.

```kusto
AzureActivity
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d)
| where ResourceProvider contains "Microsoft.Compute" and OperationName == "Create or Update Virtual Machine"
| where HTTPRequest contains "PUT"
| project VMName = Resource, Created_On = format_datetime(EventSubmissionTimestamp,'dd-MM-yyyy-HHtt'), User = Caller
| distinct Created_On, VMName, User
| order by Created_On
```

In my case, I was trying to get the VMs deleted in the last 7 days. For some reason the time wasn't displaying properly for the query below, hence I had to convert it to my timezone.

```kusto
AzureActivity
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d)
| where ResourceProvider == "Microsoft.Compute" and OperationName == "Delete Virtual Machine"
| where HTTPRequest contains "DELETE"
| extend MyTimeZone = EventSubmissionTimestamp + 8h
| project VM_Name = Resource, Deleted_On = format_datetime(MyTimeZone, 'dd-MM-yyyy-HHtt'), User = Caller
| distinct Deleted_On , VM_Name , User
| order by Deleted_On
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy with Az module:

```
$VM = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName RGNAME -Name VMNAME
$VM.TimeCreated
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this Azure CLI command in your subscription. It'll list the VMS and their creation dates and time.

az vm list --output json --query "[*].{VM:name, Creation:timeCreated}" -o table